# jquery ajax post selectbox array by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I want to do an ajax request to update the status of an item, but for one or many selected item.

So how can I post all the selected checkbox items to process it on the handle page?

Here is some code I use., but it will only post one `item` to the process page.

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="select-all" name="item[]" id="item[78]">
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="select-all" name="item[]" id="item[182]">
</td>
```

And the javascript

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}}"
    }
});

var formData = {
    item: $('input[name=item\\[\\]]').val(),
}

var type = "POST";
var my_url = "/posturl";

$.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: my_url,
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(formData);
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('Error:', data);
    }
});
```

Comment: you probably want to give those checkboxes a value?

Comment: yes, now with the answer of harish it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assign the unique name to each checkbox
2. Put all checkboxes in a `form` tag (all input fields in a single form).
3. Use [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) for collecting data from form
4. store data in `var formData`

Code:

```
<form id="form-name">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item[1]">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="item[32]">
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}}"
    }
});

var formData = $('#form').serializeArray();

var type = "POST";
var my_url = "/posturl";

$.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: my_url,
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(formData);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log('Error:', data);
    }
});
```

This will post an array of items to the url.[image: image upload]

Comment: Yes thank you, I changed a little bit but than it works! I will update your post with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did same thing in minor different way.

I got list of checkbox and names contain their id.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="bulkChecked" name="{{$value->id}}">
```

And Inside your event handler

```
var ids = [];

$(".bulkChecked:checked").each(function () {

    ids.push($(this).attr("name"));

});
```

So at this point you have got ids of checked boxes. No you can pass 'ids' array with your ajax call